# How to add an image below the cell.backgroundview in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I had an application in which i am using an image as the background of the cell in iphone.I am doing that like this

`cell.backgroundView = [ [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"chat_cell1.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(6,39,15,60)] ]autorelease];`

now i am adding another image to the content view for the same cell.its a small image.i need to show that image close the background view with some part of the background view actually above this image.I need this bellow the background view.`

```
 [[cell contentView] insertSubview:imageView belowSubview:cell.backgroundView];
             [[cell contentView]sendSubviewToBack:imageView];
```

`but it is still showing above the background view.can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a slight correction in my code is done the trick for me.Happy to share with all

`[[[cell backgroundView] superview] insertSubview:imageView belowSubview:cell.backgroundView];`

Answer (score 1):

Create a single `UIView` containing both the background image and the new image view. Then set the background view to be this container.

Answer (score 1):

For that kind of behaviour do not use the cell's background view. Just use :

```
[cell addSubview:firstView];
[cell addSubView:secondView];
```

There is not point of using cell's contentView or backgroundView, you only make it complicated. Treat the cell like an ordinary UIView, and just add UIViews as subviews.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UIImageView *imv = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(6,39,15,60)];
    imv.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"user.jpg"];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:imv];
    [imv release];
```